# Como fazer funcionar maps em APIs antigas e novas ao mesmo tempo?

Tags: android, google-maps

Estou lutando há mais de mês para fazer funcionar uma simples app que mostrasse um mapa. Consegui, conforme um outro post, que funcionasse na versão 3.2, mas não na 4.1 e, pelos comentários dos amigos, isto deveria ser por causa do hardware do tablet da 4.1 do que propriamente um problema da aplicação em si.

Por enquanto, desisti disto.

Tenho uma outra pergunta: como fazer funcionar o Google Maps tanto na versão 3.2 (aquela que funciona) quanto na versão 2.2?

A pergunta decorre da impossibilidade de se usar fragmentos na versão 2.2 e, pelo que li, a API Key obtida do API Console da versão atual exige fragmentos.

Como sair deste problema?

Answer (score 2):

O Android suporta fragmentos em versões antigas (até 1.6) desde que você substitua as classes relacionadas a essa funcionalidade por classes equivalentes que se encontram na biblioteca de suporte revisão 4. Para utilizar essas classes, você precisa incluir o .jar dessa biblioteca no classpath do seu projeto. Esse .jar fica em `{diretório_do_android}\sdk\extras\android\support\v4\android-support-v4.jar`.

Veja quais classes você deve substituir:

```
android.app.Fragment --> android.support.v4.app.Fragment
android.app.Activity --> android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity
android.app.FragmentManager --> android.support.v4.app.SupportFragmentManager
com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment --> com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment
```

Observe que no caso de `Fragment` o nome da classe não mudou, apenas o nome do pacote. Cuidado com os imports.

Sua `Activity` deve estender então de `FragmentActivity`, dentro dela você deve chamar `getFragmentSupportManager()` ao invés de `getFragmentManager()` e você deve substituir as demais classes pelas versões correspondentes.

Veja detalhes neste [post](http://nglauber.blogspot.com.br/2012/12/android-google-maps-v2.html).

Comment: Obrigado, Piovezan.