# Geração da SHA1 - Outro modo de fazer?

Tags: android, google-maps

Todos os tutoriais apontam para um só caminho, na hora de gerar a sequência SHA1 ou MD5 para ser usada no Google Console, a fim de se obter a API Key a ser posta no arquivo manifest.xml.

Isto é, dizem para ir para o *prompt* de comando e digitar aquela longa sequência de

```
keytool  -list -alias [apelido] -keystore [nome do arquivo keystore] -keypass [senha]
```

que vai retornar MD5 ou SHA1, dependendo se você usa -v ou não como mais uma chave no comando acima.

Entretanto, notei que o SHA1 gerado pelo comando é o mesmíssimo que se obtém quando se gera a APK, através da ação de menus do Eclipse (Export, projeto, chave, nome da apk). A última janela, quando o Eclipse compila a aplicação exibe os mesmos caracteres.

Minha pergunta: ao invés daquele trabalhão de digitar pelo prompt do 'dos' do Windows, não é mais prático compilar a aplicação, copiar o SHA1, levar para o  Google Console, colar lá junto com o pacote da aplicação, pegar a API Key gerada, voltar à aplicação e editar a tag do manifest.xml e recompilar para fazer valer o uso do mapa?

Comment: Amigos, já descobri a resposta, muito boa: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6528691/fragments-in-android-2-2-1-2-3-2-0-is-this-possible

Comment: Esse comentário pertence a outra questão que você postou: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4488/como-fazer-funcionar-maps-em-apis-antigas-e-novas-ao-mesmo-tempo

Comment: Coloque a solução aqui como resposta e aceite ela. Você ajuda outras pessoas e ainda pode ganhar reputação.

Comment: Caro Piovezan, ando tão atordoado nesta programação com Android, porque sou autodidata, que ando confundindo os posts.

Comment: Caro bigown, deixo de fazer as coisas até em meu próprio benefício porque ignoro (às vezes não consigo entender as várias premiações, vantagens, desvantagens - é muita coisa!) e me falta tempo atualizar. Estou correndo contra o relógio. Você comentou para eu pôr a solução como resposta e aceitar, eu não entendi bem o que quis dizer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voce pode gerar a chave pelo eclipse indo para a barra de menu e:

Window(janela)->Preferences(preferencias)->Android->Build e voce vera um campo preenchido com  a chave SHA1.

Olhe na foto:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]